# How to apply "acceptsFirstMouse" for app build with SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, macos-catalina

Let's imagine that I have an app for macOS (Catalina).

This app is not hidden. But another app is activated (front of all/ top most)

I want to catch click on the button/any other view *(I'm using swiftUI, so everithing is a view)* in case of click on my app.

How can I do this?

---

UPD: how to apply "acceptsFirstMouse" for app build with SwiftUI?

Comment: You can't, simply

Comment: @matt in case of this is impossible, "ubar" cannot exist, but it is exist. As any other "external" and not build-in dock alternative. And such apps HAVE SUCH BEHAVIOR. So.... You're not right. It's possible, but you just don't know how.

Comment: Chill out Andrew, matt is an expert and writing best books on iOS programming and Swift Language. Your question is ambiguous, you should've tagged it with macOS specifically.

Comment: So now it's just a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128015/make-osx-application-respond-to-first-mouse-click-when-not-focused and many others.

Comment: It is not duplicate because of `SwiftUI` tag. There is no such information for swiftUI on SO and any any other resource. I have checked.

Comment: You are the one who has elected to throw away the yummy goodness of Cocoa and use SwiftUI instead. `acceptsFirstMouse` is Cocoa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, for now there is no such instrument in SwiftUI API, but... it is not standalone in a desert, and Apple did not say that it is a replacement for Cocoa, moreover they show us how to integrate them and use best of both...

So, here is possible approach...

```
import SwiftUI
import Cocoa

// Just mouse accepter
class MyViewView : NSView {
    override func acceptsFirstMouse(for event: NSEvent?) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}

// Representable wrapper (bridge to SwiftUI)
struct AcceptingFirstMouse : NSViewRepresentable {
    func makeNSView(context: NSViewRepresentableContext<AcceptingFirstMouse>) -> MyViewView {
        return MyViewView()
    }

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: MyViewView, context: NSViewRepresentableContext<AcceptingFirstMouse>) {
        nsView.setNeedsDisplay(nsView.bounds)
    }

    typealias NSViewType = MyViewView
}

// Usage (somewhere in your SwiftUI view stack)
...
      Text("Click me")
        .padding(20)
        .background(Color.yellow)
        .overlay(AcceptingFirstMouse()) // must be on top (no confuse, it is transparent)
        .onTapGesture {
            print("Label tapped")
        }
...
```

[backup](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/Answers/Integrate_accept_first_mouse.md)